# Slick proof of isomorphism of quotients of direct sums of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have just encountered this problem on quotients of direct sums of modules and their isomorphisms stating as follows:

> For all that follows R is a ring with unity (not necessarily commutative) and M is a left R-module.
>
> a. For submodules N, L of M, we are to prove $ (N+L) / N \cong L / (N \cap L) $.  DONE
>
> b. For submodules N, L of M, we are to prove if we have a direct sum $ N \oplus L $ then we have $ (N \oplus L) / L \cong N $. DONE
>
> c. We have submodules N, L of M with direct sum $ N \oplus L $ and two submodules $ L_0 $ of $ L $ and $ N_0 $ of $ N $. We are to prove the following $R$-module isomorphism: $ (N \oplus L) / (N_0 \oplus L_0) \cong N/N_0 \times L/L_0 $. DONE
>
> d. We have the following direct sum $ M = N_1 \oplus ... \oplus N_n $ and for $  k \leq n $ we have k submodules $ L_1 \subseteq N_1 ,..., L_k \subseteq N_k $ with defining $ L = L_1 +...+ L_k $. We are to first prove $ L = L_1\oplus \cdots\oplus L_k $ (DONE) and the following isomorphism of $R$-modules $$ M/L \cong (N_1/L_1) \times \cdots\times (N_k/L_k) \times N_{k+1} \times\cdots \times N_n.$$

My problem here is I cannot seem to find a humane way of showing the isomorphism of part d which is fairly intuitive but I am quite certain there is a slicker way of utilizing parts a,b,c and the direct sum in d, all of which I have done, in order to show the module isomorphism in part d. I certainly appreciate all help, thanks to all helpers.

Comment: Please add some parenthesis to the various quotients. As written, they do not quite make sense.

Comment: Maybe you missed that $K/\{0\}\simeq K$?

Comment: @user26857 : Actually I do know this and the other building blocks but how to put them together is where I am stuck

Comment: Then maybe you missed that $L=L_1\oplus\cdots\oplus L_k\oplus\{0\}\oplus\cdots\oplus\{0\}$ as submodule of $M$.